# Distribution of iOS Apps to selected customers

Tags: ios, distribution

I have developed an iOS application and I'm ready to start distributing, but my business model is a bit peculiar.

The app itself has an undefined value, as it is part of a suite of applications. In my business model, the user buys this suite of appliations, which includes a PC software (the one that has more value), iOS app, Android app and WinRT app.

I don't want to make this app public on the app store.

One alternative that would fit my needs perfectly is the redemption codes that Apple makes available for business (VPP or volume purchase program). But reading it's terms and conditions, Apple states that I cannot resell redemption codes

I'm sure I'm not the only one with such demand, how people solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the business to business program but that means apple takes a cut of your sales..

Another alternative is making a public app store app and have either username and passwords for your users or even better redemption codes (that activate the app) like you want to do anyway, its fine to sell your redemption codes by your own means and then have the user enter it in the app so they can use it..

Comment: Given that Apple has its own IN-APP Purchase and IN-APP Subscription models, I wonder if those terms and conditions prevent me from creating my own subscription model, as you suggest.

Comment: You should be fine in my opinion... I developed an app for a company that is supose to be only for some of their clients, the app is on the public appstore, and you need some configuration and user name and passwords to use the application, I think redemption codes will be alright..